# PHP Laravel sending mail returns validation error and empty fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mail

I'm building a `laravel`-app and when I try to send a mail I get a validation error which I cannot localize.

My form looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('help') }}">
   <input type="hidden" name="job" value="{{ $job->id }}">
    @csrf
   <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" required>
   <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
   <input type="tel" pattern="^[0-9-+s()]*$" placeholder="Phonenr." name="phone" required>
   <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

and my controller I have this:

```
use Validator;
use App\Mail\HelpMail;

class HelpController extends Controller {

   public function __invoke(Request $request) {
      $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => ['required', 'string'],
        'email' => ['required', 'email'],
        'phone' => ['required'],
        'job' => ['required', 'integer', 'exists:jobs,id'],
      ]);

      ...
   }
}
```

Then in my HelpMail

```
class HelpMail {
   use Queueable, SerializesModels;

   public $job;
   public $name;
   public $email;
   public $phone;

   public function __construct($data) {
     $this->job = $data['job'];
     $this->name = $data['name'];
     $this->email = $data['email'];
     $this->phone = $data['phone'];
   }

}
```

This returns an error like: `name must be filled out`, `email must be filled out` and `phone must be filled out`. 
When I comment out the validation, the mail goes through, but then the fields/payload is empty, and I have absolutely no clue why this happens, since I use the same method on my contact form.

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't know if you copied and pasted directly from your code but you are missing a closing quote on your name text input `input type="text <--missing quote`

Comment: Have you tried what is the result of `$validator` ? Because not seeing all of your code, the validation might have failed but you still proceed with the next line, because when you use the facade you have to do the check yourself. So try `dd($validator->fails());` after the validation.. and print the errors using `$validator->errors()` if any.

Comment: @nakov `dd($validator->fails())` returns `true` but when I do `print_r($validator->errors())` right after, I get nothing... or where should I print it out?

Comment: It's missing the code where you are passing data to job.

Comment: @ST80 when you do `dd` it dies after that so it won't print anything, try `dd($validator->fails(), $validator->errors());`

Comment: @nakov ok, good to know! It turned out that the issue came from somewhere else, since the form ist send with `jquery/axios` the issue was localized there (missing fields). Thanks anyway and sorry for the inconvenience :-s

Comment: @ST80 happy it worked out, I gave an answer below showing you two ways to handle the validation, one is the manual way which you use in case you need to respond with json instead of view, and the other is handled directly by laravel, returns the errors message bag in the response.

Comment: @nakov Very nice, I will add your answer to my code-snippets and also accept the answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in your case using the facade you will have to manually handle if any errors:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => ['required', 'string'],
        'email' => ['required', 'email'],
        'phone' => ['required'],
        'job' => ['required', 'integer', 'exists:jobs,id'],
      ]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    // either with view, or use response()->json($validator->errors);
    return view('view_name')->withErrors($validator->errors);
} else {
    return view('view_name');
}
```

You can instead use the validation on the request object, which will return back to the view with the errors message bag in it:

```
public function __invoke(Request $request) {
      $request->validate([
        'name' => ['required', 'string'],
        'email' => ['required', 'email'],
        'phone' => ['required'],
        'job' => ['required', 'integer', 'exists:jobs,id'],
      ]);

      ...
}
```